# Textbox text binding to Properties.Settings.Default.myString does not update myString

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I got a string `Properties.Settings.Default.myString` and two TextBoxes

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding myString}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding myString}"/>
```

When I type text into **textBox1** and change Focus, the text in **textBox2** is updated with the text I just entered in **textBox1**.

What confuses me is that `Properties.Settings.Default.myString` never updates with the text I enter in either of the TextBoxes. I did confirm this by inspecting `myString`in the debugger after changing it.

**My question is, why this change in the textBox is not reflected in the bound variable `myString`?**

Complete XAML (WPF-App):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textBoxDataBinding"
    xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:textBoxDataBinding.Properties" x:Class="textBoxDataBinding.MainWindow"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="212" Width="318">
<Window.DataContext>
    <Properties:Settings/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>

    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding myString}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding myString}"/>

    <!-- Button does: textBlock.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.myString; -->
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I did, but that is not the issue, since `Save()` will only save the current state of `myString`. But `myString` does never update. Thanks for the hint, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

You are not binding to the `Default` singleton settings, you are creating a new set of Settings. What you need to bind to is `Settings.Default` singleton instance.

E.g.

```
 <Window DataContext="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}">
```

Alternative solution:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Default.myString}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Default.myString}"/>
```

First answer for historical reason:

---

You need to bind to teh Defaul properties
You need to make sure either

1. The DataContext is your `Properties.Settings.Default` object.
2. Make the source of the binding as `Properties.Settings.Default`

This works for me:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=myStrring,Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=myStrring,Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Or cleaner syntax:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.SO29048483"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        Title="SO29048483" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding myStrring}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding myStrring}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And if you want to udpate it before lose focus:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding myStrring, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my question. The data binding per se is working. I said that a change on textBox1 is reflected in textBox2. But the source is never updated to reflect that change.

Comment: what is your source? Can you show where you are setting the DataContext

Comment: Your solution is not working for WPF, but you got me on the right track! I edited your answer and marked it. I have one question though. When using the Visual Studio Data Binding creation dialogue (http://i.imgur.com/TgfVn2A.png), why is it showing "wrong" settings (marked blue)?

Comment: My answer came from a brand new WPF project which compiled and worked :| Probably some namespace changes....